# What UI Framework utilize VS-Code? (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

I searched in the Documentation for Visual Studio Code. I have investigated this question extensively and found no clear answer.

I like to develop for VS-Code and with VS-Code.

A sneak look into the source of Visual Studio Code on GitHub looks like VS-Code uses mainly Bootstrap as UI Framework?

I only want to know if my guess is correct. Or if VS-Code utilize also other UI Framework(s) ?

Comment: When you like to start develop extensions for VS-Code, you may start with : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Comment: If your extension uses a complex GUI use webview, with HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Comment: Thank you both for your replies!
I mean a lower level. No Extensions. Webview is hiding the framework.
So if i like to contribute to VS-Code himself, which UI Framework does it use?